# Calling internal function Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use a function in the GoogleMap "initialize" function. 
What I have got :

```
<script>
function initialize(){
  // initialization parameters

    function drop(){
      //code to drop a marker
    }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Then, I have a button in order to call the function "drop()". In the GoogleMap tutorial, I read the code and the calling is made as following :

```
<div id="panel" style="margin-left: -52px">
    <button id="drop" onclick="drop()">Drop Markers</button>
</div>
```

And I have the error : **drop() function is not defined...**

I read about functions imbrication in Javascript, but I do not find how can I realize this calling. I find a lot about calling a internal function of an objet. Here is about function into function only.

Thank you a lot for your time answering this.

Comment: that function only exists within the scope of the initialize function

Comment: There is no way to call that function unless it's exposed to the outside world. As shown here, `drop` exists only in the scope of the `initialize` function.

Comment: A mentioned above, `Drop()` is only in the scope of `initialize`, if you're able to take out the drop function and make a call to it when inside the initialize function, i suggest taking that route.

Comment: Ok, I understand the post of erikrunia and Dave Newton... The question is : How is it posible to write it in a tutorial if it does not work? 

@StephenSugumar, I tried to do this. To define drop() outside this function and to call drop() in initialize(). The same problem occurs (and I had thinked to add "map" in argument).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use inline handlers. Use `addEventListener` instead

```
function initialize(){
  // initialization parameters

    function drop(){
      //code to drop a marker
    }
    //ta-da!
    document.getElementById('drop').addEventListener('click', drop);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

HTML

```
<div id="panel" style="margin-left: -52px">
    <button id="drop">Drop Markers</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @YuryTarabanko, 
Thank you a lot, it works perfectly. I did not have this vision of listeners and this way to process. 

I will remember it! 

Have a nice evening.

Answer (score 0):

drop() is defined in the initialize() scope, so it won’t be accessible from the global scope.